# Google Script sending automated email on delay

Tags: google-apps-script

I’m having a particular issuing when using Google script editor.

I having a spreadsheet that once a form is submitted, it pulls the name from the form and pulls their email. Then sends them an email.

For some reason, it’s sending the email, heavily delayed at about an hour. There’s only been two changes since it’s been working. 1. For some reason the spreadsheet keeps reverting to Central Time instead of Eastern (messing up the time stamps) 2. I added array formulas at the top to solve for the form inputting new rows.

I can paste code here in a bit, but was hoping anyone had some insight.

I’m using GmailApp.sendemail

Here is the code

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var range = e.range;
    var row = range.getRow();
  //This is the section you change to line up the rows with the values you are trying to pull
  //The var defines the variable and the blue text is naming the return value
    var emailToColumn = 2; // B
    var answerColumn = 4; //D
    var statusColumn = 6; // F
    var questionColumn = 3; //C
    var emailStampColumn = 7; //G
    var sessionColumn = 10;
    var assignedToColumn = 5; //E
  //This tells the code which row to check and pull values from
    var stampCheck =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 3").getRange(row, emailStampColumn).getValue();
    var answerValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 3").getRange(row, answerColumn).getValue();
    var emailToValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 3").getRange(row, emailToColumn).getValue();
    var questionValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 3").getRange(row, questionColumn).getValue();
    var statusAnswer = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 3").getRange(row, statusColumn).getValue();
    var sessionValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 3").getRange(row, sessionColumn).getValue();
    var assignValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 3").getRange(row, assignedToColumn).getValue();


     //This is a check to make sure email is answered
    if ( statusAnswer == 'Assigned' && stampCheck.length == 0 ) {
     var emailAssign = assignValue;  
      //This is the actual email text
        var subject = "You Have Been Assigned A Question";
  var htmlStr = "";
  htmlStr+= "<p>Hello,</p>";
  htmlStr+= "<p>This is to inform that you have been asked a question</p>";
  htmlStr+= "<p><b>Navigate to this link </b></p>";
  htmlStr+= "<p><b>Your question is in column C:</b></p>"; 
  htmlStr+= "<p>" + questionValue + "</p>";
  htmlStr+= "<p>Thank you!</p>";

  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAssign, subject, "", {
    htmlBody: htmlStr})


    //var statusColumn = range.getColumn(); //5 
    //var answerColumn = 3;
    //if ( range.getColumn() === answerColumn ) {
        //if ( e.value.length > 0 ) {
            //if ( SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses").getRange(range.getRow(), range.getColumn()) ) {

            //}
        //}
    //}
  //var progress = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses").getRange(range.getRow(), range.getColumn() + 2).getValue();
//   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Column changed FROM   ' + e.oldValue + '   TO   ' + e.value + '   AT   ' + range.getA1Notation() + '\t' + answerValue + '   ' + statusAnswer);
   //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(answerValue.length + '   ' + statusAnswer);
    }

      //THIS IS WHERE SECOND PORTION OF CODE BEGINS

   //This is a check to make sure email is answered
    if ( answerValue.length > 0 && statusAnswer == 'Completed' && stampCheck.length == 0 ) {
     var emailTo = emailToValue;  
      //This is the actual email text
  var subject = "Territory Tech Forum Answer";
  var htmlStr = "";
  htmlStr+= "<p>Hello,</p>";
  htmlStr+= "<p>This is line one of the email</p>";
  htmlStr+= "<p><b>This is line two - it is bolded because it has a bold tag surrounding it</b></p>";
  htmlStr+= "<p><b>Your question:</b></p>"; 
  htmlStr+= "<p>" + questionValue + "</p>";
  htmlStr+= "<p><b>The answer to your question:</b></p>";
  htmlStr+= "<p>" + answerValue + "</p>";
  htmlStr+= "<p>Thank you!</p>";

  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, "", {
    htmlBody: htmlStr})

  var stampValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 2").getRange(row, emailStampColumn).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
    //var statusColumn = range.getColumn(); //5 
    //var answerColumn = 3;
    //if ( range.getColumn() === answerColumn ) {
        //if ( e.value.length > 0 ) {
            //if ( SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses").getRange(range.getRow(), range.getColumn()) ) {

            //}
        //}
    //}
  //var progress = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses").getRange(range.getRow(), range.getColumn() + 2).getValue();
//   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Column changed FROM   ' + e.oldValue + '   TO   ' + e.value + '   AT   ' + range.getA1Notation() + '\t' + answerValue + '   ' + statusAnswer);
   //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(answerValue.length + '   ' + statusAnswer);

}
}
```

Comment: Pasting your code will help to identify the issue. I assume you use a `Form Submit` trigger rather than a time-driven trigger?

Comment: using onedit, code is above now, just didnt have access to it at time of post

Comment: You cannot use `onEdit` to trigger on form submit - `onEdit` only detects human made changes, not automatic insertion of new form submissions. This why your funciton fires with delay (probably when somebody happens to make an actual edit to the sheet). Use instead the installable `onFormSubmit` trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use onFormSubmit and the [FormResponse class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response) to gather item responses and send the email. OnEdit is based on user edits of a spreadsheet which isn't exactly what happens when a form is submitted

Have you tried logging the start time of the script and tracking the time throughout the process? You can use the code below in multiple locations throughout the script.

`var processStartTime = new Date();
Logger.log('processStartTime: '+ processStartTime)`

This will help identify if the script is running slowly or is being triggered at the wrong time.

Check if the script your triggered by [onFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit()), it should not be Time based.

Is the script stored in the form, in the spreadsheet or is it a [Standalone](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone)? This is unlikely to be causing the problem, but is possible.

Comment: Code is added now, sorry just didnt have access at time of post. Unfortunately the processStartTime did not help. I should have mentioned it is OnEdit rather than on Submit

Comment: See new answer. Try using on onFormSubmit instead.